# Firebase database change data notify with RecyclerView Adapter Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Data Structure:

[image: data structure]

```
factoryConfigs.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            if (dataSnapshot != null && dataSnapshot.getValue() != null){
                Log.i("onChildAdded", "onChildAdded " + dataSnapshot.toString());
                try{
                    FactoryConfig config = dataSnapshot.getValue(FactoryConfig.class);
                    configs.add(config);
                    mFactoryList.scrollToPosition(configs.size());
                    mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(configs.size());

                }catch (Exception e){
                    Log.e("FactoryFragment", e.getMessage());
                }
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
            Log.i("datachange", "dataChanged" + dataSnapshot.toString());

            mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
```

I have factory_line data that increases as needed.
I need to know what database has to change so I can modify my list and notify the adapter. I can't figure out how to find the adapter position where  the data has been changed.

Answer (score 0):

Get the position of the of the item in the adapter and apply use notifyItemChanged(int position).

Answer (score 0):

My advice would be to use a FirebaseRecyclerAdapter. (https://medium.com/android-grid/how-to-use-firebaserecycleradpater-with-latest-firebase-dependencies-in-android-aff7a33adb8b). Now ever time the data changes the firebase recycler adapter will automatically update and you will not need to call notify.

in your case:

```
Query queryReference = factoryConfigs.orderBy("business_name");

FirebaseRecyclerAdapter adapter = new FirebaseRecyclerAdapter(FactoryConfig.class, R.id.recyclerItemLayout, viewHolderClass.Class, queryReference) {

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder viewHolder, int position) {
        FactoryConfig fc = getItem(position);
        //populate recycler accordingly
    }
};
```

use the above adapter to replace the current adapter